# Want to listed my app on android app chooser dialog when user click on any link from different app

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I want to listed my app in app chooser dialog (like google, Mozilla are shown in chooser dialog when we click on any link) and it was perfectly work but when i click in any link from youtube it does not show my app in Android chooser dialog.

My manifest file code is :-

```
<activity
            android:name=".mvp.BroswerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|stateHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="developer.android.com"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"/>

        </intent-filter>

 </activity>
```

It is working when we click on any other site but in case of youtube is not working.

I have also try to add the sharing intent in my code but there is no luck to solve this.

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Please suggest what can i do to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `in case of youtube is not working` what exactly you do in youtube?

Comment: Read this document https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: Hello **Vladyslav** I just want when user click any link in youtube then my app is also listed with google, Mozilla in android chooser dialog.

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwal use `@Vladyslav` to respond, or I won't get a notification and will never know you responded. `link in youtube` youtube-what? web site, or the youtube app?

Comment: @Vladyslav, Thank you for your guidance, and i have tried in youtube app.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I have notice one thing when i select google from chooser dialog then after redirecting to google another dialog open for chooser and in that my app is listed. And that all thing happens in youtube app.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube sends a `text/plain` intent with `ACTION_SHARE`, unless you are talking about sharing a video. So it is obvious that it won't show up any `ACTION_VIEW` intent.

Comment: I also add the **ACTION_SHARE** intent to my code but it's not working.